# In k-Fold cross-validation, is a new model initiated for each fold in Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I know how to perform CV with basic utility functions such as `cross_val_score` or `cross_validate` in Sklearn.

However, I started using XGBoost, so to be able to use its `fit` params, I have to cross-validate using the `split` function of CV splitters. My question is, should I init a new model for each fold like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import xgboost as xgb

cv = KFold(5)

for train_idx, test_idx in cv.split(X, y):
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
    model.fit(X[train_idx], y[train_idx], eval_metric='rmsle')
    ....
```

or init a single model outside the for loop like this:

```
cv = KFold(5)

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()

for train_idx, test_idx in cv.split(X, y):
    model.fit(X[train_idx], y[train_idx], eval_metric='rmsle')
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I already received the answer from someone else. Turns out, in each fold, you *should* initialize a new model.